# Encrypt and decrypt files with password

Tags: linux, file, encryption, password-encryption

I'm using linux and I basically want to encrypt a file using a password.

I've tried using `gpg -c myfile` for encryption, and that works fine, it asks me for a password and encrypts it. But it only asks for a password when encrypting.

I want a way to encrypt a file and if you want to decrypt it you have to give the same password that it was encrypted with.

---

If there's a python library that would work too since I can put that on a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several alternatives to create passowrd protected files under Linux.

**GnuPG**

GnuPG can be used to encrypt data and create digital signatures.

To encrypt and decrypt a data.txt file, use gpg command as follows:

```
$ gpg -c data.txt
$ gpg data.txt.gpg
```

**mcrypt**

mcrypt allows you to create password protected files similarly to GnuPG

To encrypt and decrypt a data.txt file, use mcrypt command as follows:

```
$ mcrypt data.txt
$ mcrypt -d data.txt.nc
```

**OpenSSL**

The OpenSSl Cryptography Toolkit can also be used to encrypt and decrypt files and messages.

To encrypt and decrypt a data.txt file, use the openssl command as follows:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in data.txt -out data.txt.enc
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in data.txt.enc -out data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because of `gpg-agent`, a daemon that manages private keys and which is used as a backend for gpg. It caches your passphrases for some time by default. You can configure that with the following options (from `man gpg-agent`):

```
--default-cache-ttl n
              Set the time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  The default is 600 seconds.  Each time a cache entry is accessed, the entry's timer is reset.  To set an entry's maximum
              lifetime,  use  max-cache-ttl.   Note that a cached passphrase may not evicted immediately from memory if no client requests a cache operation.  This is due to an internal
              housekeeping function which is only run every few seconds.

--max-cache-ttl n
              Set  the  maximum time a cache entry is valid to n seconds.  After this time a cache entry will be expired even if it has been accessed recently or has been set using gpg-
              preset-passphrase.  The default is 2 hours (7200 seconds).
```

One way to clear the cache is to reload the gpg-agent : `gpgconf --reload gpg-agent`

You can use `gpg -c myfile && gpgconf --reload gpg-agent` to encrypt your file, after which the password will be asked if you try to decrypt it with `gpg myfile.gpg`